# Access JSON data in PUT request - Jersey Dropwizard

Tags: java, rest, jersey, put, dropwizard

I am using jersey dropwizard and trying to update a record as follow:

```
    @PUT
    @Path("api/v1/tasks/{taskId}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @UnitOfWork
    public Task updateMyTask(@PathParam("taskId") long taskId, @QueryParam("description") String description) {
        ...

        System.out.println(description); // Always `null`

        ...
    }
```

My request data:

```
{ "description": "dummy description" }
```

My problem is that I am unable to access the data coming in PUT request. It always shows as `null`. I already have tried this with `@FormParam`, no luck.

**EDIT:**

After [Sam's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37490802/1047207) response, I have made suggested changes and getting following exceptions:

```
@PUT
@Path("api/v1/tasks/{taskId}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@UnitOfWork
public Task updateTask(Task task, @PathParam("taskId") long taskId) {
    ...

    System.out.println(task.getDescription());

    ...
}
```

Returning error:

```
{
  "code": 400
  "message": "Unable to process JSON"
}
```

Comment: Do you get any other output for the error message? Is there a log file anywhere? It would be good to know why the JSON deserialization is failing.

Comment: Not much in log: `127.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2016:19:26:10 +0000] "PUT /api/v1/tasks/1 HTTP/1.1" 400 47 "-" "-" 92`. Not sure how I can see the detailed logs in dropwizard app

Comment: Does the POJO class have a no-args constructor?

Comment: Yes: `public Task() {  }`

Comment: I'm nearly out of ideas, without more detailed error message :(. How are you making the request?

Comment: Requesting from chrome rest client.

Comment: Okay I'm out of ideas.

Comment: No problem @Sam, Thanks for your efforts. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The data isn't a `@FormParam` or a `@QueryParam`, it's just the body of the request, so it doesn't need any annotations.

What it does need is a POJO that describes the format of the JSON data you're providing. For a simple `String` value that could look like this:

```
class Task {
    String description;
    ... // other fields
}
```

Your `@Consumes` annotation is confused, too. You've annotated the method as `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)`, but you're trying to send it JSON data. Declare your method as:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
...
public Task updateMyTask(Task task, @PathParam("taskId") long taskId) {
    System.out.println(task.description); // not null any more
}
```

You'll need to make sure you have JSON mapping enabled in Jersey.

Comment: I was just experimenting with `@Consumes`. Had tried with `APPLICATION_JSON`, however, thanks for attracting my mind there.  I have more attributes that I would pass in the data. I am not really convinced about creating an individual class for each attribute of `Task` model. Please check EDIT in my question

Comment: @RAJ you would define all the JSON attributes in the same class. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I misunderstood your original post. Sounds like you have the right idea :)